# java regex contains certain string

Tags: java, string, match

I need to workout a way to test a string contains some words or not, doesn't matter uppercase or lowercase. 
E.g

```
String ppe1 = "Mask"
String ppe2 = "mask"
String ppe3 = "MASK"
```

then when I do

```
return ppe1.matches("[A-Za-z]*mask")  // it should return true
```

or

```
return ppe2.matches("[A-Za-z]*mask")  // it should return true
```

or

```
return ppe3.matches("[A-Za-z]*mask")  // it should return true
```

I know above regex is totally wrong,, but just wish to demo my idea for what I need, 
In a simple word,  as long as string contains term 'Mask' , doesn't matter 'MASK' or 'mask'  or 'mASk' or 'masK' or whatever combo,  regex should detect the term and always return true.
Please suggest with code example.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An arguably easier approach would be to force the case and then use `contains`:

```
return myString.toLowerCase().contains("mask");
```

Comment: ohh right... that s easy :)